# How do i setup Kali Linux while in text mode

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux

I am a newbie at Linux, in fact this is the first time i'm using linux.
Having installed Kali Linux i keep getting the text mode display, a youtube tutorial shows that i need a display manager and how to set it up, but i can't run

> sudo apt-get update

or

> sudo apt-get install

gdm3 because i am not connected to the net ( a step i skipped while setting up due to ignorance).
Please how do i set up a WIFI connection or install a usb modem in text mode?
Thanks. I'm stuck at black n white

Comment: Please take a look at [tour]. This questions should be asked on [superuser.se]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to enable the WiFi by running:

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

Comment: i tried but it returned -bash: nmcli: command not found

Answer (score -2):

Just edit /etc/network/interfaces and write:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp 
                wpa-ssid {ssid}
                wpa-psk  {password}
```

After that write and close file and use command:

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Replace {ssid} and {password} with your respective WiFi SSID and password.

Comment: nothing was returned by stdout, is that a problem?

Comment: Euh no. You need to have a response. Listening on LPF/wlan0/44:...
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/44:...

Comment: After running dhclient, it says “Cannot find device wlan0”